# How do I price a game that sells internationally online?

Tags: online, sales

If I have a downloadable game or in-game item that I need to sell for a fixed amount in all countries, how do I work out how to set the price? My local currency is UK pounds. Would I come up with a round number figure in £ and let customers in other countries deal with the currency fluctuations? Should I try to display the figure in the local currency if possible? Would it be better to price the game in dollars or euros and deal with the currency fluctuations myself? How are other games handling this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plimus, at least, gives you lots of different options;

- Fixed price in one currency, or set values of each currency
- Various rounding options on currency conversions

As an example, 12.34 turns into..

- 12.30
- 12.35
- 12.50
- 12.95
- and so on, depending on the options you choose

As to what price point to choose for your game, and whether you want to anchor to one currency or define unique price for each, depends on the market you're entering. The iDevice market, for instance, is a completely different beast from Steam. In any case I'd look at what the other games in your target market are doing, and start from there.

It does seem, for instance, that Europeans always get higher prices than the folks in the US. Maybe we're just stupid enough to pay higher prices.

Comment: USA prices tend to be lower for a couple reasons: list price excludes VAT, and USA market has lower expectations for warranty and number of included translations.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest just finding a round figure in your own currency and let the customers deal with the fluctuation.

It looks smoother and most people have a rough estimate of how much their own currency is worth in comparison to the big world currencies. (Euro,USD,GBP)

Because a customer usually just does a fast conversion in their heads they will still buy the game even though their currency is weak in comparison to GBP.

Some payment services like PayPal previews what the cost in the local currency will be before you pay.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you have access to a merchant account in multiple currencies (they usually only work in your home currency) in which to receive the international payments.  I would say specify the price in GBP / USD / EUR and then you will have most things covered.

As a rule of thumb however, most stuff denominated out of the States in USD is usually cheaper than we pay here in the UK.  If you accept payments via Paypal then you can keep all the currencies in your Paypal account and hedge as appropriate.

Good luck.